# a while loop in Newton Raphson in R

Tags: r

I tried to write the newton raphson program in R:

```
mle_estimate <- function(x,start, eps, t_i_begin, error_begin){

      t0 <- start  
      t_i_next <- t_i_begin
      error <- error_begin
      while (error >= eps) {


      t_i_next <- t0 - first_partial(x, t0)/second_partial(x, t0)

      error <- abs(t_i_next - t0)  

      t0 <- t_i_next


      }

      return (t_i_next)
}
```

However when I tested the program using:

```
x <- c(1.77, -0.23, 2.76, 3.8, 3.47, 56.75, -1.34,
4.24, -2.44, 3.29, 3.71, -2.4, 4.53, -0.07, -1.05,
-13.87, -2.53, -1.75, 0.27, 43.21) 

mle_estimate(x, 10, 5, 3, 12)
```

I got a warnings of
Warning messages:

```
1: In while (error >= eps) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In while (error >= eps) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In while (error >= eps) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In while (error >= eps) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Does anyone know why the message of "the condition has length >1 ..."? because it seems my condition in the while loop is only a comparison of the current value of the variable "error" and "eps"?

Edit: This is my partial derivative:

```
first_partial <- function(x, theta_current){
  fp <- 0
  fp <- sum((2*(x-theta_current))/((x-theta_current)^2 + 1))
  return (fp)
}

second_partial <- function(x, theta_current){
  sp <- 0
  sp <- (-2*(x-theta_current)*((x-theta_current)^2+1) + 4*(x-theta_current)*(x-theta_current))/(((x-theta_current)^2 + 1)^2)

}
```

Comment: Where are `first_partial` and `second_partial` defined? One or both is probably returning a vector with more the one element. Check `length(error)` and `length(eps)` each time before doing the `if()`

Comment: @MrFlick is right - `t_i_next` almost certainly has a length greater than one which feeds into `error`. Here's an example highlighting the warning message: `x <- 1:2; while(x > 1) print(x)`

Comment: Hello, I have added the partial derivative to the code as well now. Could anyone comment as to why the Warnings? thanks

Comment: Hi Chase and MrFlick, but my first Partial and second Partial only output a number in each iteration.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed when I add print(first_partial) inside the mle_estimate function, it somehow gives me a length of vector of 20 values.   But when I just use first_partial(x,0.3) say outside of the function, I get one single value.

Comment: could anyone suggest how to fix the problem? how come inside the mle_estimate function, the first_partial function returns a vector, but when I use first_partial, say first_partial(x, 0.4), it gives me a single number which is what i want. I am not sure why it would give a vector inside the function.